# How to configure checkpoint and earlystopping so that no warning will be issued?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

My model definition is below. Two callbacks are used. I want to monitor val_accuracy and early stopping is used based on loss.

```
checkpoint_filepath = '/tmp/checkpoint'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    save_weights_only=True,
    monitor='val_accuracy',
    mode='max',
    save_best_only=True,
    verbose=1)
early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=1)
history = model.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_ds, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint_callback])
```

Why does it always complaint about "WARNING:tensorflow:Can save best model only with val_accuracy available, skipping."?

Answer (score 0):

Please compile your model using 'metrics=["accuracy"]' parameter, like:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="nadam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Then it should work.